# Which data structure for representing possible navigations between a game's screens?

Tags: data-structures, game-development

I am trying to find an appropriate data structure for representing available navigations between a game's screens.

- Using a *linked list*, a node can only have one node after it : inappropriate.
- Using a *tree* seems up to the job as nodes can have many children nodes but it's inconsistent in the sense that a supposedly children item *Options* can have a parent *Title* as a children. Also how am I supposed to represent the infinite sequence of the case *Title -> Race -> Title -> Race ...* without endlessly repeating it in my tree ? Still, this is the best structure I found to accomplish the job.

Here is an example of the possible sequences :

1. Title

   - Options
   - Race
2. Options

   - Title
   - Race
3. Race

   - Options
   - Title

Do you know whether a *tree* is the way to go or if there's a better structure for this job ?

---

**Edit:**

There is a great library for creating graphs for C#/WPF : http://graphsharp.codeplex.com/

It uses http://quickgraph.codeplex.com/ internally.

Here's a small example :

[image]

Code-behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using GraphSharp.Controls;
using QuickGraph;

namespace WpfApplication15graph
{
    internal class ScreenVertex
    {
        public string Hello { get; set; }
    }

    internal class ScreenEdge : Edge<ScreenVertex>
    {
        public ScreenEdge(ScreenVertex source, ScreenVertex target)
            : base(source, target)
        {
        }
    }

    internal class ScreenLayout : GraphLayout<ScreenVertex, ScreenEdge, ScreenGraph>
    {
    }

    internal class ScreenGraph : BidirectionalGraph<ScreenVertex, ScreenEdge>
    {
    }

    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // build graph
            var screenGraph = new ScreenGraph();
            var screenVertex1 = new ScreenVertex {Hello = "1"};
            var screenVertex2 = new ScreenVertex {Hello = "2"};
            var screenVertex3 = new ScreenVertex {Hello = "3"};
            screenGraph.AddVertex(screenVertex1);
            screenGraph.AddVertex(screenVertex2);
            screenGraph.AddVertex(screenVertex3);
            screenGraph.AddEdge(new ScreenEdge(screenVertex1, screenVertex2));
            screenGraph.AddEdge(new ScreenEdge(screenVertex2, screenVertex1));
            screenGraph.AddEdge(new ScreenEdge(screenVertex1, screenVertex3));
            screenGraph.AddEdge(new ScreenEdge(screenVertex3, screenVertex1));
            screenGraph.AddEdge(new ScreenEdge(screenVertex3, screenVertex2));
            ScreenLayout.Graph = screenGraph;

            // get connections for a particular vertex
            IEnumerable<ScreenEdge> inEdges = screenGraph.InEdges(screenVertex3);
            IEnumerable<ScreenEdge> outEdges = screenGraph.OutEdges(screenVertex3);
        }
    }
}
```

XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication15graph.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:WPFExtensions.Controls;assembly=WPFExtensions"
        xmlns:controls1="clr-namespace:GraphSharp.Controls;assembly=GraphSharp.Controls"
        xmlns:wpfApplication15Graph="clr-namespace:WpfApplication15graph"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="SvTemplate" DataType="wpfApplication15Graph:ScreenVertex">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Hello}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="controls1:VertexControl">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls1:VertexControl">
                            <Border CornerRadius="5" Width="50" Height="50" Background="LightBlue">
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Vertex}"
                                                  ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource SvTemplate}" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <controls:ZoomControl>
            <wpfApplication15Graph:ScreenLayout x:Name="ScreenLayout"
                                                HighlightAlgorithmType="Simple"
                                                LayoutAlgorithmType="Circular"
                                                OverlapRemovalAlgorithmType="FSA" />
        </controls:ZoomControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Are you looking for a [Directed Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph)?

Comment: I think so, thank you ! Can you add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to consider a [Directed Graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph).

It's similar to a tree, but with fewer restrictions.  You just have nodes with one-way links between them.  You can make the structure as clean/well-organized/neat/messy/chaotic as you wish.

Be careful if your menu system becomes complicated - DGs can get messy.

Comment: I've been using it previously but totally forgot about its existence, thanks !